# graphing multiple items with graphite

Tags: graphite

I want to generate graphs in graphite, directly, without asking the user to use the
arcane graphite UI buttons and methods, so as to graph a variety of things on a 
single graph.

So far, all I can graph is one item per graph with:

echo "some/path/to/some/arbitrary/name  `date +%s` | nc graphiteserver 2003

That correctly puts the point associated the the time since the epoch onto
the graph named by the path at the graphite server.

I am *assuming* (but do not know) that the above is not possible and that
one must use the graphite UI buttons. No? Yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this [using the URL API](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/url-api.html#graphing-metrics):

```
http://your.graphite-web.url/render?target=metric1&target=metric2
```